# How to find where time is used when using ServiceFabric and HttpClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to figure out where time is used in my application.

ServerA sends to serverB using the following function:

```
protected async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    using (var telemetryRequest = _telemetry.ExternalRequest("Outgoing call -> ", request.RequestUri.OriginalString, "", false))        // Creates a DependencyTelemetry
    {
        using (var response = await Client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Error = HandleDeserializationError
                });

            return returnObject;    
        }
    }
}
```

The call is then picked up in serverB using a custom middleware:

```
public class MyCustomkMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var request = _telemetryClient.InCommingRequest($"Incoming request: {context.Request.Method})            // Creates a RequestTelemetry
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The middleware is configured duing startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ContextInitializer contextInitializer, )
{
    app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomkMiddleware>();
}
```

If you look at the log, you see that the call takes a lot of time, but I dont really understand why. My guess is that there is a high startup and shutdown time because of something silly we do. How can I narrow it down or find the problem?

[image: duration of events]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out how to debug this, but the slowdown was caused by services.AddScoped. Changing it to services.AddSingleton() greatly improved the performance!